# Mysql Query, comparing tables reseults

Tags: mysql

When I execute these queries separately, I get the results below `$sql1->first` 2 columns, `$sql2->second` 2 columns:

```
$userid='AD0004';
$comp_code='AD';

$sql1 = "SELECT DISTINCT CCCOMPANY, CCCNTY
        FROM D.TMTBCNTC
        WHERE CCCOMPANY='$comp_code'";

// //gets USER & their counties
$sql2 = "SELECT DISTINCT UCCOMPANY, UCCNTY
        FROM D.TMTBCNTU
        WHERE UCUSERID='$userid'
        AND UCCOMPANY='$comp_code'";

CCCOMPANY CCCNTY UCCNTY UCCOMPANY
AD      AT              
AD      BB      BB      AD
AD      BE      BE      AD
AD      BR      BR      AD
AD      CM      CM      AD
AD      CO      CO      AD
AD      DE      DE      AD
AD      EB      EB      AD
AD      EP      EP      AD
AD      FB      FB      AD
AD      GB              
AD      GU      GU      AD
AD      GV      GV      AD
AD      HA      HA      AD
AD      KF      KF      AD
AD      KN      KN      AD
AD      MB      MB      AD
AD      MG      MG      AD
AD      PF      PF      AD
AD      TA      TA      AD
AD      UB      UB      AD
AD      WI      WI      AD
```

What I want to do is join the columns `CCCOMPANY=UCCOMPANY && CCCNTY=UCCNTY` and also return the blank fields when there isnt a match found.

The issue i am having is the query seems to loop back through itself, meaning I get 22 counties per company and 20 counties per user, which comes out to 20x22=>440 results, I want 22 results AND one query.

edit1:

```
$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT c_t.CCCOMPANY, c_t.CCCNTY, (
CASE WHEN u_t.UCUSERID='$userid'
THEN  'exists here'
END
) AS UserOnSite
FROM  D.TMTBCNTC as c_t
LEFT JOIN D.TMTBCNTU AS u_t ON u_t.UCCOMPANY = c_t.CCCOMPANY
WHERE c_t.CCCOMPANY =  '$comp_code'";
```

Output:

```
    AD | AT |
    AD | BB |
    AD | BE |
    AD | BR |
    AD | CM |
    AD | CO |
    AD | DE |
    AD | EB |
    AD | EP |
    AD | FB |
    AD | GB |
    AD | GU |
    AD | GV |
    AD | HA |
    AD | KF |
    AD | KN |
    AD | MB |
    AD | MG |
    AD | PF |
    AD | TA |
    AD | UB |
    AD | WI |
    AD | AT | exists here
    AD | BB | exists here
    AD | BE | exists here
    AD | BR | exists here
    AD | CM | exists here
    AD | CO | exists here
    AD | DE | exists here
    AD | EB | exists here
    AD | EP | exists here
    AD | FB | exists here
    AD | GB | exists here
    AD | GU | exists here
    AD | GV | exists here
    AD | HA | exists here
    AD | KF | exists here
    AD | KN | exists here
    AD | MB | exists here
    AD | MG | exists here
    AD | PF | exists here
    AD | TA | exists here
    AD | UB | exists here
    AD | WI | exists here
```

EDIT2:

```
$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT c_t.CCCOMPANY, c_t.CCCNTY, (
    CASE WHEN u_t.UCUSERID='$userid'
    THEN  'exists here'
    END
    ) AS UserOnSite
FROM  D.TMTBCNTC as c_t
LEFT JOIN D.TMTBCNTU 
    AS u_t 
    ON u_t.UCCOMPANY = c_t.CCCOMPANY 
WHERE c_t.CCCOMPANY =  '$comp_code' 
    AND u_t.UCCNTY = c_t.CCCNTY";


    AD | AT |
    AD | BB | exists here
    AD | BB |
    AD | BE | exists here
    AD | BE |
    AD | BR | exists here
    AD | BR |
    AD | CM | exists here
    AD | CM |
    AD | CO | exists here
    AD | CO |
    AD | DE | exists here
    AD | DE |
    AD | EB | exists here
    AD | EB |
    AD | EP | exists here
    AD | EP |
    AD | FB | exists here
    AD | FB |
    AD | GB |
    AD | GU | exists here
    AD | GU |
    AD | GV | exists here
    AD | GV |
    AD | HA | exists here
    AD | HA |
    AD | KF | exists here
    AD | KF |
    AD | KN | exists here
    AD | KN |
    AD | MB | exists here
    AD | MB |
    AD | MG | exists here
    AD | MG |
    AD | PF | exists here
    AD | PF |
    AD | TA | exists here
    AD | TA |
    AD | UB | exists here
    AD | UB |
    AD | WI | exists here
    AD | WI |
```

Comment: the second result is not bad, not sure why your server throws 2 results if the user exists...

Comment: My guess is that its because its an iSeries

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT c_t.CCCOMPANY, c_t.CCCNTY, (
 CASE WHEN u_t.UCUSERID='$userid'
 THEN  'exists here'
 END
) AS UserOnSite
FROM  D.TMTBCNTC as c_t 
LEFT JOIN D.TMTBCNTU AS u_t ON u_t.UCCOMPANY = c_t.CCCOMPANY
WHERE c_t.CCCOMPANY =  '$comp_code'
AND u_t.UCCNTY = c_t.CCCNTY "; // additional where clause
```

You naming of columns and tables doesn't really makes it easier.. But this should give you the result you're looking for

This should output as follows:

```
CCCOMPANY CCCNTY UserOnSite
AD       |  AT  | NULL            
AD       |  BB  | exist here
AD       |  BE  | exist here
AD       |  BR  | exist here
AD       |  CM  | exist here
AD       |  CO  | exist here
AD       |  DE  | exist here
AD       |  EB  | exist here
AD       |  EP  | exist here
AD       |  FB  | exist here
```

Second better attempt: **Edited**

```
$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT c.CCCOMPANY, c.CCCNTY, (
 SELECT (
  CASE WHEN u.UCUSERID='$userid'
  THEN  'exists here'
  END
 )
 FROM D.TMTBCNTU as u
 WHERE u.UCUSERID =  '$userid'
 AND u.UCCOMPANY = c.CCCOMPANY
 AND u.UCCNTY = c.CCCNTY 
 LIMIT 1
) AS UserOnSite
FROM  D.TMTBCNTC AS c 
WHERE c.CCCOMPANY = '$comp_code'";
```

This should work better

Comment: Thats close, but it prints the company list twice, does not include the user results.

This is an old database, I dont have any choice on the column and table names.

Comment: Show me the result it puts out and what you need

Comment: When I run your second query I get this: Warning: db2_fetch_array(): Fetch Failure in

Comment: try running it in phpMyAdmin and see the error message there

Comment: Im running this on an iseries, I cant dump this into phpMyAdmin.

Comment: what is the who;e error messag you get? My guess is that you may have to add a `limit 1` to the subquery after `AND u.UCCOMPANY = c.CCCOMPANY`